# base class for fstream and wfstream

Tags: c++, fstream

So I am implementing an IO class that internally uses in some cases `fstream` and in other cases `wfstream`.

```
class IO
{
public:

  // open file stream 
  IO(string filepath, bool iswide);

  void read(int val);
  void read(bool val);
  void read(string val); // if m_iswide == true is not called
  void read(wstring val);

  void write(int val);
  void write(bool val);
  void write(string val); // if m_iswide == true is not called
  void write(wstring val);

private:
  bool m_iswide;          ///< use wfstream if true
  std::fstream m_fstream;
  std::wfstream m_wfstream;
};
```

#### Question

Is there any type that can be used as a base class (with read/write interface of course) for both streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  A wide character stream is something completely
different from a narrow character stream, and uses a completely
different `streambuf`.  If your class tries to use two different
instances, they will have two different buffers, and two
different, independent file positions; reading characters from
one of the streams would not remove them from the input of the
other.

Note that even in C, although you only had one `fopen`,
independently of the type, once you'd accessed it for wide
characters, attempting to access it for narrow, and vice versa,
was undefined behavior.

Comment: what do you mean by _once you'd accessed it for wide characters_?

Comment: @idanshmu Although you don't specify it in `fopen`, each stream has an orientation, either wide or byte.  You cannot use wide character input/output functions on a byte oriented stream, nor byte input/output functions on a wide oriented stream.  The orientation is determined by the first input/output function you call on the stream, e.g. `fgetc` (byte) or `fgetwc` (wide).

Comment: That is very important information. I thought I could use those functions interchangeably.

Comment: So is it a good practice to have two streams open for the same file. I guess you need to carefully synchronize file pointer of both streams and that is error prone

Comment: @idanshmu You'ld have to syncrhonize the file pointers, which more or less means a `seek` before each access, and a `tell` after, and you'd have to synchronize the buffers as well, which means a flush after every write.

Comment: OK. let's go back again to your comment: _each stream has an orientation, either wide or byte_. what if I always use __byte orientation__ and convert the bytes to wide string on a need bases? will that do the trick and prevent me from managing two streams? the solution of course will be to work with `C FILE` and use only `fread` and `fwrite` which uses `void *` anyway

Comment: @idanshmu That's about the only solution I can think of.  In which case, you can just go ahead and use `std::fstream`.  And you only need special handling when the user requests wide character input and output.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid those two classes hierarchies only meet in `ios_base`. You could probably create a template so the user can chose either one of the streams.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only common base is `std::ios_base`, and that's useless.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io for an overview of the hierarchy

and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base for that base-class.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to type-erase the stream with the technique used in boost::any and similar.

Take a look at [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html)

For the technique used to implement this kind of erasure, take a look [here](https://github.com/sean-parent/sean-parent.github.io/wiki/Papers-and-Presentations).

It is the talk about value semantics and concept-based polymorphism.

Example would be equivalent to:

```
class ClassWithCommonInterface {
 ...
};

ClassWithCommonInterface f(stream);

f.read(...);
...
```

EDIT: Re-reading your question I see that you have a closed set of types.
Use boost.variant to hold both types. You can use visitors to choose the real read operation based on the type you are using.

You can also use reference semantics if you want with Boost.TypeErasure.

Comment: Even with Boost TypeErasure, there will be two distinct underlying stream objects.  Each with its own buffer, file position, etc.

Comment: The question says if there is a common base class. There's not. I think my suggestion is the closest thing you could do, IMHO.

Comment: It's no different than having two separate variables in his class.  It doesn't solve his problem (which he did explain).